# Defining a function (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This works already, but I want to optimize a bit:

```
df['Total Time'] = df['Total Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: (int(x[0])*60.0) + int(x[1]) + (int(x[2]) / 60.0))
```

I am taking a timestamp (string) in Excel which represents Hours:Minutes:Seconds and turning it into a float which represents minutes. This is easier for me to play around with compared to the string.

I have to do that for 15 columns though. I have read that lambda is a 'throwaway' function. Is it better to define a function (to split and then to turn the values into minutes) and apply it to each column instead? Would I loop through the columns (not all columns, but 15 of about 30)?

On a separate file, I have another technique which is performing the exact same task (turning a timestamp into minutes):

```
df2['Total Time']= pd.to_timedelta(df2['Total Time'])
df2['Total Time'] = df2['Total Time'] / pd.offsets.Minute(1)
```

Is one method inherently better or faster than the other?

Edit:
I was getting an error when I tried the timedelta method.It looks like some timestamp strings have incorrect values which are not being interpreted correctly.

I am hoping someone will provide a function I can use to apply/map everything to several columns at once efficiently. I am not too familiar with def and return functions (I learned basic pandas before I learned basic python, just for practical purposes.. slowly learning though). Need to turn those timestamps into minutes

ValueError: cannot create timedelta string converter for [09:38:010]

Comment: You could just measure this but generally `apply` should be the last resort as it doesn't scale as well as its a for loop and if called on a series it executes per row. With respect to turning it into a function so you can apply to 15 columns you put your code for you last method into a function and then call `apply` on a df, this will call it for each column but it will try to execute the function on the whole Series

Comment: I would imagine the dt accessors are the best/fastest way:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#dt-accessor

Comment: I would also consider using `map()` instead of `apply()`.

Comment: Thanks, can someone post a code example of how they would do it so I can vote for the best answer and see a real example based on my problem as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the idomatic (but more general soln) is actually slower, see the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6755)

```
In [28]: pd.set_option('max_rows',12)

In [29]: s = Series(pd.timedelta_range('0',freq='s',periods=10000).format())

In [30]: s
Out[30]: 
0       00:00:00
1       00:00:01
2       00:00:02
3       00:00:03
4       00:00:04
5       00:00:05
          ...   
9994    02:46:34
9995    02:46:35
9996    02:46:36
9997    02:46:37
9998    02:46:38
9999    02:46:39
dtype: object
```

Works well on a given regular format

```
In [31]: %timeit s.str.split(':').apply(lambda x: (int(x[0])*60.0) + int(x[1]) + (int(x[2]) / 60.0))
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop
```

This will parse almost anything (you can set `coerce=True` to force invalid values to `NaT`),
but is doing regex-matching, so somewhat slower.

```
In [32]: %timeit pd.to_timedelta(s) / pd.offsets.Minute()
10 loops, best of 3: 82.8 ms per loop
```

So looking for a volunteer to write the timedelta parser in c/cython to greatly improve this perf.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like the string method works better, but ideally we should be using timedeltas. The other thing is that some of my strings randomly have an extra character in the seconds column (see my edit). It would be a shame to turn them into NaT since this is someone's login time at work and impacts schedule adherence and other metrics.

Comment: Also, what about .map vs .apply? And is it better to have a separate line of code for each column I am doing this to, or is it better to define a function and apply that to each column? It looks a bit messy to have this split lambda function 15 times in a row (15 timestamp columns to be converted to minutes)

Comment: just wrap it up in a small function, and either apply it across the columns, or since you prob don't have too many of these, just do it per column.

Comment: you *should* be using ``to_timedelta`` as its handling a much more general set of timedeltas and invalid parsing.